# Unable to use Spring Data MongoDB + Spring DataJPA together with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jpa, spring-boot

When I try to use Spring Data JPA and Spring Data MongoDB together with SpringBoot it is assuming my Mongo Entities also JPA entities and throwing errors.

I have Person JPA entity and PersonRepository which extends JpaRepository. And I have User Mongo Entity and UserRepository which extends MongoRepository.

When I start the application I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.sivalabs.app.mongoentities.User
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:219)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 66 more
```

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Can you please post your Spring configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put your Mongo and JPA entities in separate packages (it looks like you've already done that) and then use `@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses=SomeMongoEntity.class)` and `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=SomeJpaEntity.class)` so that Spring Data knows where to find the Mongo and JPA entities respectively. You can see these annotations in action in Spring Boot's [`MixedMongoRepositoriesAutoConfigurationTests`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.1.x/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MixedMongoRepositoriesAutoConfigurationTests.java).